# How to use double quote and plus sign in url parameter php?

Tags: php, html

I am using double quotes, plus sign, & sign and many more special characters in url parameter

1. mysite.com/Screen Size-5.5"

i have done urlencode for 5.5"

```
$var = urlencode(5.5");
```

it is not working in this case.

1. I have to do double urlencode in case of & sign.
   mysite.com/Brand-Barnes+%26+Noble
2. I am using + sign in url even it is also not working.
   mysite.com/Internet%20Connectivity-Wi-Fi%2B%252B%2B3G

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: It works fine here: `<?php $var = urlencode('5.5" + 10"'); print $var; ?>

5.5%22+%2B+10%22`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong is how you are encoding. That's a syntax error. Try

```
<?php
$value=urlencode('Size-5.5"');   // Didn't have proper quotes here.
$url="http://www.google.com?q=$value";
echo $url;
?>
```

Works Perfectly. This will take you here

https://www.google.com/?q=Size-5.5%22

Which is searching for `5-5"`

Answer (score 0):

You did mistake in your code, right is:

```
$var = urlencode('5.5"');
```

Comment: no actually i am using an variable instead.
$param='5.5"';
$var = urlencode($param);

Answer (score 0):

Use `base64_encode()` and respectively `base64_decode()` instead while posting URL parameters.